# Count number of appearances of a row in a tall matrix (list of lists)?

Tags: python

I have a tall (3,000,000 by 2) matrix, represented as a list of lists (A list with 3 million elements, each being a list with two elements) and I need to count the number of times each pair appears as a row (there's a finite number of possible pairs, around 5000). This is what I do so far, but it's highly inefficient:

```
for a in list1:
    for b in list2:
        count_here = tall_matrix.count([a,b])
```

Any ideas on how to make this quicker?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might not have access to the construction step, but a nice way is to keep the count when putting the elements into the container.

Comment: could you add a small example of your data?

Comment: A hash will be a better option with key such as a1_a2 => count. a1 should be smaller than a2. Once done you are done, it is easy to use this to get counts. But to make this hash, it will still take O(n) time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count the occurrences of a list item in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

This is damned simple using `collections.Counter`. Since your list contains sub-lists, and sub-lists are not hashable, you'll need to convert them to tuples first:

```
In [280]: x = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [4, 5]]

In [282]: c = collections.Counter(map(tuple, x))

In [283]: c
Out[283]: Counter({(1, 2): 2, (3, 4): 1, (4, 5): 2, (5, 6): 1})
```

`c` stores the counts of every single pair in your list.

Comment: @tobias_k A counter is a defaultdict of sorts: `In [284]: c[(100, 20352)];
Out[284]: 0`

Comment: Well, in this case I learned something new today :-). Still, might add a hint w.r.t. converting the sub-list to tuple *for lookup*, as well.

Comment: @tobias_k Already mentioned it man :) `Since lists are not hashable, you'll need to convert them to tuples first`

Answer (score 0):

Counter should do the trick :

Test for performance (using IPython) :

```
In [1]: import random
In [2]: a=[(random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)) for i in range(3000000)]
In [3]: from collections import Counter
In [4]: %time c = Counter(a)
CPU times: user 940 ms, sys: 52 ms, total: 992 ms
Wall time: 891 ms
```

Comment: This will fail for OP, as it is a list of non-hashable lists.